# VBA not updating PivotTable date ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I don't know where I am going wrong but it not working neither giving any error. I am trying to Update my Pivot table with cell values that should filter the given date ranges in cell G3 & G4. But unfortunately not updating the table.

Below is the VBA I am using.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

'This line stops the worksheet updating on every change, it only updates when cell
'G3 or G4 is touched

If Intersect(Target, Range("G3:G4")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Set the Variables to be used
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim Field As PivotField
Dim EDate As String
Dim SDate As String

'Here you amend to suit your data
Set pt = Worksheets("Report").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set Field = pt.PivotFields("Date")
SDate = Worksheets("Report").Range("G3").Value
EDate = Worksheets("Report").Range("G4").Value


'This updates and refreshes the PIVOT table
With pt
Field.ClearAllFilters
Field.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=SDate, Value2:=EDate
pt.RefreshTable

End Sub
```

Comment: It works for me. I notice you are missing an `End With` statement. Also, did you put the code in the Worksheet module for `Report`?

Comment: Yes. I was having the same mistake. Inserted End With and now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it myself. Posting the answer below, might be of someone's help.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

'This line stops the worksheet updating on every change, it only updates when cell
'G3 or G4 is touched

If Intersect(Target, Range("G3:G4")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Set the Variables to be used
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim Field As PivotField
Dim EDate As String
Dim SDate As String

'Here you amend to suit your data
Set pt = Worksheets("Report").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set Field = pt.PivotFields("Date")
SDate = Worksheets("Report").Range("G3").Value
EDate = Worksheets("Report").Range("G4").Value


'This updates and refreshes the PIVOT table
With pt
Field.ClearAllFilters
Field.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=SDate, Value2:=EDate
pt.RefreshTable
End With

End Sub
```